# Min-cut variation

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms

I'm searching for an algorithm to do the following

I have a graph $G = (V, E)$ and a set of terminal pairs $\{(s_i, t_i)\}$. I need to find a cut smaller than a given quantity $k$, such that there is a path connecting at least a terminal pair in both subgraphs created by the cut.

Comment: As stated, the trivial cut (with no edges) works.  In every (in fact the only) component of $G\setminus\varnothing$, there is a path connecting at least one (in fact every) terminal pair.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I need a cut that divides $G$ into 2 subgraphs.